# Автоматический переход в соседнюю ячейку

Tags: vba, excel

После проведения предметного тестирования заполняется вот такая таблица:

[image]

Таблица заполняется вручную. После того как курсор устанавливается на первое задание, начинается нажатие последовательно следующих клавиш: "**0(1)** **->** **стрелка вправо** -> **0(1)** -> стрелка вправо..." И так до конца, как вы поняли. Я поставил ограничения, чтобы в ячейки можно было вводить только 0 или 1.

Есть ли способ сделать так, чтобы после нажатия **0/1** соответствующая цифра вставлялась, но и еще чтобы курсор сам переходил на одну ячейку вправо? Я тогда бы просто использовал две клавиши (0 и 1). Догадываюсь, что в любом случае необходимо будет использовать VBA.

Comment: Вариант более "автоматический".

Внести в одну ячейку "11100", нажать кнопку. Данные с этой ячейки разносятся поячечно и считается общая сумма.
Так сделать или по Вашему варианту?

Comment: Если не скромничать, то про "11100" я тоже думал. И все-таки можно ли, как я описал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока не закончен ввод значения, нельзя определить, когда переходить на другую ячейку.

Ввели значение, нажали *Enter, стрелку вверх, вправо, Tab*... Вот оно, событие. И это событие можно отследить.

Код вставить в модуль листа (войти в редактор *VBA* - *Alt+F11*)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub ' выход, если выделено более одной ячейки
    ' выход, если изменяемая ячейка не принадлежит заданному диапазону
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B3:F10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        ' между  With/End With все, что с точкой слева
        ' (продолжение ссылки), относится к Target
        With Target
            If .Column = 6 Then ' если последний столбец с баллами
                .Offset(1, -4).Select ' сместить выделение на нижнюю строку
            Else ' если не последний столбец
                .Offset(, 1).Select ' выделить ячейку правее
            End If

            ' сумма по строке
            Cells(.Row, 7).Value = Val(Cells(.Row, 2).Value) + _
                    Val(Cells(.Row, 3).Value) + Val(Cells(.Row, 4).Value) + _
                    Val(Cells(.Row, 5).Value) + Val(Cells(.Row, 6).Value)
'            Cells(.Row, 7).Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(.Row, 2), Cells(.Row, 6)))
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Проверяется изменение в диапазоне *B3:F10*.

При изменении значения ячейки последнего столбца диапазона (в данном случае - *F*) в заданном диапазоне выделяется первая ячейка следующей строки, при изменении в любой другой выделяется ячейка правее.

Суммировать можно и по отдельности, и функцией листа *СУММ*(строка закомментирована)

---

Второй вариант - заполнение диапазона после введения данных.

Диапазон для заполнения *B3:F10*. Перед заполнением ввести значения в диапазон *H3:H10* (например: "01101" в одну ячейку).

Код разместить в общем модуле (в редакторе *VBA*), для вызова макроса можно нарисовать кнопку на листе.

```
Sub SetAboutValues()
' определение переменных
Dim ArrValue ' массив
Dim i As Long, j As Long ' счетчики
    ' заносим в массив введенные данные
    ArrValue = Worksheets("Лист1").Range("H3:H10").Value
    ' расширяем массив на количество баллов плюс столбец для суммы
    ' с сохранением данных (Preserve)
    ReDim Preserve ArrValue(1 To UBound(ArrValue), 1 To 6)

    ' в цикле перебираем введенные данные ("строки")
    For i = 1 To UBound(ArrValue)
        ' в цикле разносим значения по ячейкам массива
        For j = 5 To 1 Step -1
            ArrValue(i, j) = Mid$(ArrValue(i, 1), j, 1)
            ArrValue(i, 6) = ArrValue(i, 6) + Val(ArrValue(i, j)) ' сумма
        Next j
    Next i

    ' выгружаем записанный массив на лист, задав размер диапазона на листе
    Worksheets("Лист1").Range("B3").Resize(UBound(ArrValue), 6).Value = ArrValue
End Sub
```